# Java IO gives me an Error

Tags: java, java-io

When I run the following code, I get an error.

```
package practicing.io;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaIO {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("xanaduout.txt");
        out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
   }
}
```

This was taken right from Sun's tutorial online. Please, tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Where do you get the error? I.e. on what line? what is the name of the error? You cant just post code with no explanation

Comment: What error do you get ? and please, edit the question, don't comment. if possible, add a stacktrace.

Comment: A runtime IO error?  Or a compile error?  What does the error say?  What line does it point to?  Do those files exist?  If so, are they in the build location or outside of it?

Comment: If you don't provide enough information, it's not worth keeping such a question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does "xanaduout.txt" exist?  In your current directory?

If not, you can always hard-code the path.  But that's not good practice :)

In any case, the error says exactly what's happening: you're trying to open a file ... and the system can't find it.

Comment: Yes, it is in the src section of me Eclipse project

Comment: "src" section doesn't count.  Try copying it to the directory *above* source (i.e. to your project root).

Comment: Hi - You just did, by clicking the "solution" box.  Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

Give the exact location of the file.

You should try

```
   in = new FileInputStream("c:\xanaduout.txt");
```

Instead of this

```
   in = new FileInputStream("xanaduout.txt");
```

Comment: You can use the latter code, but only if the file is in the same directory as the program.

Comment: All of the files are in the right place. Is there a way for me to put a screen shot on here?

Comment: @Keith Go here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow/28533#28533

Comment: You can take a screenshot and post it as image here.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: xanaduout.txt 
(The system cannot find the file specified)
```

and seems to originate from line 12 of your code:

```
at practicing.io.JavaIO.main(JavaIO.java:12)
```

Line 12 of your code is:

```
in = new FileInputStream("xanaduout.txt");
```

So you are trying to read from the file `xanaduout.txt` and Java is complaining that it cannot find the file.

**EDIT**

@Keith Mattix Edit your program to print out the path to the file it is reading from, and verify that the file does exist on disk indeed:

```
public class JavaIO {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("xanaduout.txt");
        System.out.println("My program is going to read the file " +
            file.getCanonicalPath() + " which " + (file.exists()? "" : "does not") +
            " exist on disk"); 
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        out = new FileOutputStream("out.txt");
        int c;

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(c);
        }

    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: I know what it's doing, but it shouldn't. I have the files in the directory of the .class file and the .java file

Comment: Unless you specify a direct it will be in the current working directory which doesn't have to be where the class or Java files are. All programs work this way.